# Автофокус в кастомной камере

Tags: android, android-camera

Автофокус в кастомной камере
Использую в приложении кастомною камеру (android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager). Необходимо настроить фокусировку. Кто с таким сталкивался?Может есть библиотека которая это делает?

Comment: так вам нужно вручную установить фокус, или сделать автофокус?

Comment: Желательно автофокус

Comment: У объекта Camera есть метод, что-то вроде focus(). Но никто не знает, при помощи чего вы работаете с камерой, поэтому никто вам и не скажет, как именно сделать автофокус

Comment: Исправил вопрос. Камера android.hardware.camera2.Camera

Comment: Класса android.hardware.camera2.Camera не существует. Есть только android.hardware.Camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у класса [Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) есть метод [autoFocus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#autoFocus(android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback)), который принимает колбек на окончание фокусировки. Можете использовать его.